# Remove Title of youtube video

Tags: title, youtube

How can i put a youtube video on my post without show the default title from youtube?

I  tried to put this code in the theme´s functions, but not worked.

```
function remove_youtube_controls($code){
    if(strpos($code, 'youtu.be') !== false || strpos($code, 'youtube.com') !== false){
        $return = preg_replace("@src=(['\"])?([^'\">s]*)@", "src=$1$2&showinfo=0&rel=0", $code);
        return $return;
    }
    return $code;
}

add_filter('embed_handler_html', 'remove_youtube_controls');
add_filter('embed_oembed_html', 'remove_youtube_controls');
```

Someone can help?

Thanks

Comment: you need to update  `$return = preg_replace("@src=(['\"])?([^'\">s]*)@", "src=$1$2&showinfo=0&rel=0", $code);` to ` $return = preg_replace("@src=(['\"])?([^'\">]*)@", "src=$1$2&showinfo=0&rel=0", $code);`

Comment: you have extra ` s `  in preg_replace

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Update: Try this one.. it works for youtube url in your post which is converted to iframe by wordpress.

```
   function remove_youtube_controls($code){
    if(strpos($code, 'youtu.be') !== false || strpos($code, 'youtube.com') !== false){
        $return = preg_replace("@src=(['\"])?([^'\">]*)@", "src=$1$2&showinfo=0&rel=0", $code);
        return $return;
    }
    return $code;
}

add_filter('embed_handler_html', 'remove_youtube_controls');
add_filter('embed_oembed_html', 'remove_youtube_controls');
```

Comment: where do you place it, and frankly, since youtube embeds are iframes, why should it work at all?

Comment: Doesn't work, it's an iframe. I just tried it even though I knew it wouldn't work. When you see that class, it's part of the iframe's html, not the site's html.

Comment: I changed the code hope it works.

Answer (score 2):

This works, the OP code was odd and I've never seen that usage before or the other filter. Tested and works. This code removes Title on youtube but doesn't touch anything else since the parameters wouldn't be relevant on Vimeo for example.

```
function yourprefix_remove_title_youtube_oembed( $html, $url, $args ) {

    if( strpos( $url, 'youtu.be' ) !== false || strpos( $url, 'youtube.com' ) !== false ) :

        return str_replace( '?feature=oembed', '?feature=oembed&amp;showinfo=0&amp;rel=0', $html );

    else:

        return $html;

    endif;

}
add_filter( 'embed_oembed_html', 'yourprefix_remove_title_youtube_oembed', 10, 3 );
```

Comment: this code works too. ty